# expo react-native - disable timeout to metro in tunnel connection

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, expo

My development environment is in `ubuntu` on `wsl2` with `vscode` as editor running on windows using the `remote wsl` extension. I am running it on a physical android device using the `Expo Go` app using the `tunnel connection` on the same wifi network.

Everything works fine from scanning the `QR Code` to editing the code and it auto refreshes everytime I make changes on `vscode`. The problem is when I became idle(not making changes) for a short time, the connection somehow **times out** giving the error:

`Cannot connect to Metro.`

[Cannot connect to Metro screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgWef.png)

What should be done here? How to disable the timeout if there's a way?